# SPServices get list items,values and colums dynamically from a list

Tags: spservices

I have this code, where it should call the list item after the user has clicked on the list url.

```
$j('#cd-sp-lists li a').click(function(){       
    $j("#status").fadeIn('fast');       
    $j("#preloader").fadeIn('fast'); 
    $j('#page').empty();
    var ListGUID = $j(this).attr('title');                  
        $j().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            listName: '' + ListGUID + '',
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
              $j(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var liHtml = "<li>" + $j(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";                 
                $j("#page").append(liHtml); 
                $j('#sp-lists').removeClass('is-visible');                  
                $j("#status").delay(1000).fadeOut(); 
                $j("#preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("normal"); 
              });
            }
          });   
        return false;           
    });
```

Now this  work fine. The problem is I dont want to add the fields name manualy to this script like this:
`var liHtml = "<li>" + $j(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>"` it should get all item names ,value, and colum names based on that list.

Is there away to do that?

Comment: You could do a GetList call first, but at some point, you'd need to specify what field/value you want to write out.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should first get the list fields using below service call

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetList",
    listName: '' + ListGUID + '',
    completefunc: function(xData, Status) { 
        //Extract field names
    },
    async: false
});
```

Inside `completefunc` you can have the actual call.